# How to avoid ValueWidth with AmCharts?

Tags: legend, amcharts

I'm using a 100% Stacked Column Chart in a website for a client.

In the legend, we have the value of the variable we're hovering. It gave :

[Color of the variable] [Name of the variable] [Value of the variable]

However, in some cases, when the value of the variable is too big, it's on the name of this variable.

Does someone know a way to avoid this problem without using **valueWidth** ? Indeed we have multiple legends, and this way of working is not effective when name of variables haven't the same size.

thanks in advance !

Best regards,

Answer (score 1):

You could try playing around with the equalWidths and horizontalGap properties, like in this demo:
https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/1acd9511369ff5f6d89e447be0b8f191

```
"legend": {
    "position": "bottom",
    "equalWidths": false,
    "horizontalGap": 50,
    ...
}
```

Not sure of your setup, but there's a list of other legend props and options at https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmLegend.